# Best path from origin to destination with consideration of halt time at nodes

Tags: graph, networkx, mathematical-optimization

| Origin | Destination | Arrival time | Destination time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 12:00 | 14:00 |
| A | B | 13:00 | 15:00 |
| C | D | 00:00 | 5:00 |
| B | C | 8:00 | 13:00 |
| A | C | 16:00 | 21:00 |
| D | A | 13:00 | 16:00 |

If a shipment is going from A to D. What could be the best path which will require list amount of time?

It should also consider halt time at various nodes and directional aspect.

For example in above case -

A -> D can be done with following paths

1. A - B - C - D
2. A - C - D

First one can be done with two ways as there are 2 A-B pairs

i) time taken = 2 + (18) + 5 + (8) + 8  = 41 hours

ii) time taken = 2 + (17) + 5 + (8) + 8 = 40 hours

Second one

time taken = 5 + (3) + 5 = 13 hours

**here () shows halt times**

so, in here the best path is A-C-D considering the halt times also

Answer (score 0):

You only need to transform it into a graph with suitable nodes and then you can use any algorithm for weighted graphs to get your "shortest path".
In the construction, you need to add to your graph pairs of location and time. Edges are added for possible connections of two locations and the weight of an edge is the consumed time.

Some nodes and edges of your example:

```
nodes = [(A, 12:00), (B, 14:00), (A, 13:00), (B, 15:00), ... ]

edges = [((A, 12:00), (B, 14:00), 2)), 
         ((A, 12:00), (A, 13:00), 1), 
         ((A, 13:00), (B, 15:00), 2), ....]
```

I think you also want to add "loops to the same destination at another day". So you also need to add edges like `((A, 16:00), (A, 12:00), 20))`.

Comment: But this will then change the nodes! how will then i will be able to find distance between A to D as now, name of A and D has changed.

Comment: This probably depends on your setting. If you have a start time and location, you can simply check the "closest node". If you are only interested between two locations, independent of start time, you could add extra dummy nodes for each location and connect it to all of its "timed nodes", which reminds me of another important fact: the graph should be directed.